# "Is there any way to get the data between current date to yesterday date via query in Bigquery"

Tags: mysql, sql, google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery, python-bigquery

"I am using query for getting data from current date to yesterday date in Bigquery but i am not able to get the yesterday date in BQ"

```
SELECT COUNT (*) 
FROM `urbn-edw-prod.UrbnProcessingErrors.RetailFeedDimensionError` 
WHERE errorReason = "Invalid Merchandise SKUs" 
AND DATE(ingestionTime) between CURRENT_DATE and DATE_ADD(CURRENT_DATE(), INTERVAL -1 DAY)
```

this line of code is not giving yesterday date i think

```
DATE_ADD(CURRENT_DATE(), INTERVAL -1 DAY)
```

I want to get the data from today till yesterday in BQ but i think i am using wrong query I expect output to be 500 for now but it is giving 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use:

```
WHERE errorReason = 'Invalid Merchandise SKUs' AND
      DATE(ingestionTime) >=  DATE_ADD(CURRENT_DATE(), INTERVAL -1 DAY) AND
      DATE(ingestionTime) < CURRENT_DATE())
```

Or more simply:

```
WHERE errorReason = 'Invalid Merchandise SKUs' AND
      DATE(ingestionTime) = CURRENT_DATE())
```

When you use `BETWEEN` the order of the last two operands matters.  The smaller value is first, the larger value second.

Answer (score 1):

> I expect output to be 500 for now but it is giving 0

This is because you have wrong order in below line

```
AND DATE(ingestionTime) between CURRENT_DATE and DATE_ADD(CURRENT_DATE(), INTERVAL -1 DAY)
```

instead you should use

```
AND DATE(ingestionTime) between DATE_ADD(CURRENT_DATE(), INTERVAL -1 DAY) and CURRENT_DATE
```

> this line of code is not giving yesterday date i think

`DATE_ADD(CURRENT_DATE(), INTERVAL -1 DAY)` gives you yesterday - the issue was in order as explained above - but, you can also use below instead

```
DATE_SUB(CURRENT_DATE(), INTERVAL 1 DAY)
```

Also note, when you use BETWEEN - both sides of it are included, so if you need only today's data you can just use

```
AND DATE(ingestionTime) = CURRENT_DATE
```

or for just yesterday - you can use

```
AND DATE(ingestionTime) = DATE_ADD(CURRENT_DATE(), INTERVAL -1 DAY)
```